# Resolve a Users PrincipalId to share file or Folder REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, share

Is there a way to get a users `PrincipalId` based on their email address. I'm looking to share/apply permissions to files and folders in a users OneDrive to Business drive using the REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SP.UserCollection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245043(v=office.15).aspx) contains the [SP.UserCollection.getByEmail Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245173(v=office.15).aspx) to get the user with the specified email address. The following example demonstrates how to get [SP.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246835(v=office.15).aspx) `Id property`:

```
/_api/web/SiteUsers/getByEmail('username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com')/Id
```

Alternatively you could utilize the following query:

```
/_api/web/SiteUsers?$select=id&$filter=Email eq 'username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
```